# how to hide a particular column in particular row in a grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

can any body please help how to hide a particular column in particular row in a grid using jquery. i am able to hide.
i tried with below code to hide a column.

```
    var orderSection=getSelectedGridValue("egwEnterAppealDetails","ddwOrderSection");
if(orderSection!=""){
       eval("$('[id*=ddwOrderSection]:input').attr('disabled','disabled')");
}
```

but in that case it is hiding that particular column in all rows but i don't want that. 
i am not using any jquery grid table i my js.
i hope i am clear with my query please help me out. and please give some useful reference to how to work with jquery grid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the nth-child pseudo-selector. It chooses the nth-child for every table row, thereby hiding the whole column

```
  var n = 2; column number you want to hide
  $('#myTable tr td:nth-child('+n+')').hide()
```

Or

```
  $('#myTable tr td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq(elementIndex) to hide particular column from table

$('#tblExample tr td:eq(Index)').hide();
OR
   $('#tblExample tr td:eq(Index)').css('display','none');

Example

$('#tblExample tr td:eq(1)').hide();
This will hide 2nd td from all rows within table "tblExample"

Answer (score 0):

If we want to hide the particular column use the below code:

$("#gridid").jqGrid('hideCol', "columnname");

Note:When we hide the column in header row,it will be applicable to all the rows for that particular column.